# UITableView navigation on row selection

Tags: ios, xcode

Well i have designed iPhone setting in a tableview.There are about 40 setting.So there are 40 cells in 8 sections.So there will be a different view controller for a row.What i want is to navigate to the corresponding view controller of the row without using any if-else,switch condition using indexPath.row or indexPath.section.Means i don't want to manipulate rows and sections.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not possible, since conditions allows us to perform different actions for particular requirement. And you know that. ;)

Comment: well my trainer says it possible with some way around .

Comment: How many rows do you have in your table? Here you are referring section  = row?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that like below.

I am Assuming that you are using Segue to push to different controllers

Now suppose you have one array containing 40 Dictionary as you said.
Each Dictionary contains name.

So structure will be like below

YourMutableArray

- [0] Dictionary

  - "name" : "value"

in same Dictionary you can add one more key and value as like key "seguename" and value will be identifier of segue.

so structure will look like below

YourMutableArray

- [0] Dictionary

  - "name" : "value"
  - "seguename" : "pushToSecondView"

Now you can write in your tableview's didSelectRowAtIndexPath

```
NSDictionary *selectedRowData = [YourMutableArray objectAtIndex:indexpath.row];
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:[selectedRowData objectForKey:@"seguename"] withObject:nil];
```

So you do not have to put switch conditions in didSelectRowAtIndexPath.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: yes you are right but i found some other way around too :)
Thanks